# How to change Input Port dimensions in NetChain containing NetMapOperator

Tags: neural-networks

Today I tried to build a fully convolutional 3D DeconvolutionLayer. However I encountered a peculiar problem.

Lets define the 3D layer as:

```
DeconvolutionLayer3D[n_]:=NetChain[{TransposeLayer[{1<->4,3<->4,2<->3}],NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{1<->4}]
                            ,NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{1<->3}],
                            NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{1<->2}],ConvolutionLayer[n,1,"Stride"->2]}]
```

If I then call

`NetReplacePart[DeconvolutionLayer3D@64,"Input"->{32,128,64,512}]`

I get a  3D DeconvolutionLayer. However it does not seem fully convolutional since I can not adjust the ports again and the following gives an error:

`NetReplacePart[NetReplacePart[DeconvolutionLayer3D@64,"Input"->{32,128,64,512}],"Input"->{32,256,64,512}]`

Oddly enough, if I remove the last `NetMapOperator[]` in the DeconvolutionLayer function I can adjust the input again:

```
DeconvolutionLayer3D[n_]:=NetChain[{TransposeLayer[{1<->4,3<->4,2<->3}],NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{1<->4}]
                            ,NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{1<->3}],TransposeLayer[{1<->2}],ConvolutionLayer[n,1,"Stride"->2]}]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround/hack. First my definition for `DeconvolutionLayer3D[]` was slightly wrong. Here is the right one:

```
DeconvolutionLayer3D[n_]:=NetChain[{TransposeLayer[{1<->4,3<->4,2<->3}],NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{2<->3,3<->4,1<->4}],
            TransposeLayer[{1<->3,2<->3}],NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{2<->3,1<->3}],
            TransposeLayer[{1<->2}],NetMapOperator[DeconvolutionLayer[n,2,"Stride"->2]],TransposeLayer[{1<->2}],ConvolutionLayer[n,1,"Stride"->2]}]
```

Then I define the following functions:

```
removeInputInformation[layer_ConvolutionLayer]:=With[{k=NetExtract[layer,"OutputChannels"],kernelSize=NetExtract[layer,"KernelSize"],weights=NetExtract[layer,"Weights"],grps=NetExtract[layer,"ChannelGroups"],biases=NetExtract[layer,"Biases"],padding=NetExtract[layer,"PaddingSize"],stride=NetExtract[layer,"Stride"],dilation=NetExtract[layer,"Dilation"]},ConvolutionLayer[k,kernelSize,"Weights"->weights,"ChannelGroups"->grps,"Biases"->biases,"PaddingSize"->padding,"Stride"->stride,"Dilation"->dilation]]


removeInputInformation[layer_DeconvolutionLayer]:=With[{k=NetExtract[layer,"OutputChannels"],kernelSize=NetExtract[layer,"KernelSize"],weights=NetExtract[layer,"Weights"],biases=NetExtract[layer,"Biases"],padding=NetExtract[layer,"PaddingSize"],stride=NetExtract[layer,"Stride"]},DeconvolutionLayer[k,kernelSize,"Weights"->weights,"Biases"->biases,"PaddingSize"->padding,"Stride"->stride]]


removeInputInformation[layer_TransposeLayer]:=TransposeLayer[NetExtract[layer,"Specification"]]

removeInputInformation[layer_NetMapOperator]:=NetMapOperator[removeInputInformation@NetExtract[layer,"Net"]]
```

Finally I can define a `DeconvolutionLayer3D[]` and replace its input dimensions via:

`net=NetReplacePart[DeconvolutionLayer3D@32,"Input"->{32,64,128,512}]`

`NetChain[removeInputInformation/@NetExtract[net,All],"Input"->{32,64,64,1024}]`